# PhpMyAdmin on Nginx

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I have Ubuntu 16.04.3 with LEMP installed. I added phpmyadmin, but somewhere I made a mistake:
I try to login at https://my.site.com/phpmyadmin but after login / password it brings me to the site: https://my.site.com/index.php?token=***

Adding the missing 'phpmyadmin/' 
https://my.site.com/phpmyadmin/index.php?token=*** 
lets me in.

However, I don't get the full menu. I don't have the tab Permissions.

The nginx config file contains this for phpmyadmin at one of my sites.

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share/;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
        deny all;
    }

location ~ /phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use

> root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;

instead of

> root /usr/share/;

Another easy alternate method is as below: -

install phpmyadmin using

> sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

after installing phpmyadmin, create a symbolic link from the phpmyadmin installation files to Nginx document root which is /usr/share/phpmyadmin

> sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /usr/share/nginx/html

Now enable mcrypt php module using

> sudo php5enmod mcrypt

(if you are using php7.0 check for respective command)

Restart php-fpm and nginx

> sudo service nginx restart 
>   && sudo service php5-fpm restart  or sudo service php7.0-fpm restart

in your browser use

> http://my.site.com/phpmyadmin

to access phpmyadmin.

Comment: It did not work for me. I ended up to purge phpmyadmin and installed it again. Now the command sudo phpenmod mcryp gives me twice: WARNING: Module mcryp ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available   and  afterrestarting nginx and php7.0-fpm I get a 404 at my.site.com/phpmyadmin

Comment: (I missed the t in mycrypt). I ended up to purge phpmyadmin and installed it again. After restarting nginx and php7.0-fpm I get a 404 at my.site.com/phpmyadmin    I think the sym link is wrong. I have nginx sites, but the phpmyadmin I only want in https://my.site.com